# How was the succession sequence of the Sudarshana Chakra among the avatars of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, weapon, sudarsana

I know that the Sudarshana Chakra is one of the most powerful weapons in Hinduism, just as I know that it is associated with Vishnu along with being the weapon that he used the most.

But I want to know how was the succession of the Sudarshana among the avatars of Vishnu, I want to know if Rama and Parashurama had it too.

Comment: I've heard that whenever Bhagavan discharges any weapon, sudarshana chakra is at its tip. It's like Air India One - it's not just 1 plane - any plane or vehicle that the PM is on, becomes 'one'.

Comment: Parshurama was ansha avatar, so he didn't had. But Parshuraama had Parshu (Axe) which he got from Lord Shiva. Although Raama was purna avatar but the purpose of Raamavtar was to live life exactly like human. To fulfill that purpose Raama didn't use any Vishnu's power in that avatar but instead he only used those weapons/Astras which he got from his Gurus ( "Brahma Rishi Vashishta" AND "Brahma Rishi Vishvamitra" ).

Comment: @Rishabh Actually, Rama has used the Sudarshana Chakra to kill a demon.

Comment: @wikash_hindu Which demon? As per my knowledge Raama killed every demon with his bow. But I might be wrong :)