# Did Parashurama give Sudarsana chakra to Krishna?

Tags: krishna, parashurama, sudarsana

As per [BR Chopra' Mahabharata TV serial](https://youtu.be/-J77zUIflRE), Parashurama gifted Sudrasana chakra to Krishna.

But comments under [How was the succession sequence of the Sudarshana Chakra among the avatars of Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30426/how-was-the-succession-sequence-of-the-sudarshana-chakra-among-the-avatars-of-vi) question say Parashurama didn't have Sudarsana. If so, how he could give it to Krishna?